# Lost styling of html received in mail, using nodemailer and handlebars

Tags: javascript, node.js, handlebars.js, nodemailer

I am sending an `cucumber_report.html` file to display in the body of an email. I am using `nodemailer` and `handlebars` to achieve this. It is displaying the content of html in mail without styling (please refer the last screenshot)  Is there any way I can display the css styling in email as well.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/scrumvisualize/jrebLzqf/)

```
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
var handlebars = require('handlebars');
var fs = require('fs');


var readHTMLFile = function(path, callback) {
    fs.readFile(path, {encoding: 'utf-8'}, function (err, html) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
            callback(err);
        }
        else {
            callback(null, html);
        }
    });
};

let transport = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.mailtrap.io',
    port: 2525,
    auth: {
       user: 'user_name',
       pass: 'some_password'
    }
});


readHTMLFile(__dirname + '/reports/html_simple/cucumber_report.html', function(err, html) {
    var template = handlebars.compile(html);
    var replacements = {
         username: "Some thing"
    };
    var htmlToSend = template(replacements);
    var mailOptions = {
        from: 'from@testgroup.com',
        to : 'to@sometestgroup.com',
        subject : 'Test Report',
        html : htmlToSend,
        attachments: [
             { 
                filename: 'cucumber_report.html',
                path: 'reports/html_simple/cucumber_report.html'
             }
         ]
     };
     transport.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, response) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error);
            callback(error);
        } else {
            console.log(response);
          }
    });
});
```

Original `cucumber_report.html` before sending

[image]

**Html content displayed in mail, where I lost all styling:**
[image]

Comment: You gonna need to insert your css inline. External css is unlikely to work. It might but some client can block external sources.

Comment: When I check css , i could see it was written as inline css under style section of HTML..

Comment: Open the email in Chrome and use DevTools to inspect html elements and the css. You should be able to figure out what's wrong yourself. If not, copy everything between html tags and add it to your question or if it's a lot of code place it somewhere public(codepen, jsfiddle,...) so we can check it.

Comment: I have added jsfiddle with the html. In fiddle it looks good. When I inspect the mailtrap I could the added html is wrapped inside <iframe> #document. I am unable to copy the whole iframe content to add in jsffiddle.

Comment: @Molda I have updated the question please have a look,

Comment: I have added jsfiddle with the html. In fiddle it looks good. When I inspect the mailtrap I could see the added html is wrapped inside `<iframe> #document`. I am unable to copy the whole iframe content and add into jsffiddle

Comment: What application did you use to open the email without styling shown on bottom screenshot?

Comment: I use Mailtrap.io SMTP server

Comment: So basicaly you opened it in browser i assume. So open DevTools and inspect the html and css. By selecting elements in the DevTools you should see assign css for each element. Since it renders correctly in JSFiddle it's hard to help.

Comment: Yes I can see the inline css while inspect. No worries, may be the mailtrap is blocking those one css. Appreciate your reply